# Display list items on different sharepoint portal

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

what do you think is the best way to display items from some Custom List (on sharepoint 2010) to completely different portal on SharePoint 2007 with minimum or not at all programming?

I tried with RSS and that is not what I need, so Am now stuck with IFRAME pointing some custom page on sp2010 that shows list items.

Answer (score 0):

Under SharePoint 2007, you can try tu use the BDC feature (known as Business Connectivity Services(BCS) with SharePoint 2010).

It provides the ability to SharePoint 2007 to consume external datas like SAP. It is describe in msdn with complete tutorial:
[Business Data Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for answer but I don't have SharePoint 2007 Enterprise so I can't use BDC.